# Перенос репозитория но продакшен

Tags: git, развертывание, bitbucket

Некоторое время разрабатывал проект с напарником на локальных машинах с использованием Homested, настало время выложить проект на реальный сервер. 
Репозиторий находится на bitbucket. Поставил на сервере git, сгенерил публичный ключ, ключ добавил в раздел "Ключи развертывания" на bitbucket. При выполнении команды git clone моего репозитория пишет.

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Подскажите в чем ошибка.

Comment: а сервер линуксовый? клонируете по ssh урлу или по https?

Comment: @Umed да Ubuntu там 16 по ssh пытаюсь

Comment: а url по которому клонируете ssh или https?

Comment: @Umed ssh `git clone git@bitbucket.org:<repo>`

Comment: надо сначала аутентифицироваться и создать запись о том, какой ключ будет использоваться для bitbucket, нужно запустить такую команду `ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org`

Comment: @Umed да, это я дела пишет `You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
This deploy key has read access to the following repositories: и мой ключ`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53009/discussion-between-umed-and-shadow33).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо проверить, добавлен ли Ваш приватный ключ в ssh-agent:

```
ssh-add -l
```

Если его не будет, то необходимо добавить его следующей командой:

```
ssh-add <путь_к_приватному_ключу>
```

Если окажется, что ssh-agent не запущен, то необходимо запустить его:

```
ssh-agent /bin/bash
```

Далее верифицируемся с bitbucket:

```
ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org
```

и можно клонировать Ваш репозиторий :)